# Python - Opening Images in the FabIO Module By Looping Over A Directory

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, for-loop

I'm attempting to deal with .cbf (Crystallographic Binary Format, see below for link )  files in Python. I need a way of looping over all the files in the current directory.

**Example 1**

```
# Reading in first file in FabIO.

dat = raw_input('Please Input Required Filename: ')     # Define the required filename as a string.

# Example Input: file.cbf

import fabio                                            # Import FabIO module for Python.

img_0001 = fabio.open(dat)                              # Open image from defined filename.
```

This section of the code, designed to open and display a file works perfectly. FabIO has a method of opening the next file available which is in this case of the format:

**Example 2**

```
img_0002 = img_0001.next()
```

As I have already defined img_0001 in example 1, this code would work.

How would I loop over all the files in the current directory without needing to execute the command in example 2 for every file? If there were 100 files, would it be something of the form:

**Example 3**

```
for i in range (1, 99)
   img_'i+1' =  img_000'i'.next()
```

How can I do this loop, whilst also accounting for the leading zeros?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

**Relevant Information**

**CBF Files:** http://www.esrf.eu/computing/Forum/imgCIF/cbf_definition.html

**FabIO Module:** 
http://pythonhosted.org/fabio/getting_started.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for a way to execute dynamically generated code use the [exec](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#exec) statement. So your `for` loop can be rewritten like:

```
for i in range (1, 99)
    exec ("img_%03d = img_%03d.next()" % (i+1, i))
```

However, you might simplify the lhs (left-hand-side) of the expression by using [`fabimage.getframe`](http://pythonhosted.org/fabio/api/modules.html#fabio.fabioimage.fabioimage.getframe), and IMHO storing the images in a list would simplify their later access:

```
imgs = [img_000]  
for i in range (1, 99)
    imgs.append(img_000.getframe(i))
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems exactly like what I needed.

Comment: Just implemented this and it works perfectly as intended. Just changed the %03d to %04d so I can deal with larger sets of files. I'll give the IMHO storage a go later as well. Thanks again.

Comment: If you think this answer solves your problem, please consider [accepting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it. By the way, [IMHO](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/imho) was just an initialism of *in my humble opinion* ;)